# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (PHP) (Detect browser lang and redirect)

Tags: php

I have this PHP code that detects the browser language and redirects the user to the language version of my site. If the version does not exist, the user is redirected to the English version. My main language is Spanish, whose path is: `https://example.com/`

**The problem** is that if the user speaks Spanish, **the code redirects the user to the same path:** `https://example.com/` and causes the error **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**.

How can I tell the script that **if the user speaks Spanish, it will not redirect and will stay there?** (I CAN SAY THAT THE CODE WORKS WELL redirecting to English and Portuguese)

PS: I tried with `return false` but the page remains blank.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$accept_languaje = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] : 'es';
$main_languaje   = substr($accept_languaje, 0, 2);
switch ($main_languaje):
    case 'es':
        exit(header("Location: https://example.com/"));
    case 'en':
        exit(header("Location: https://example.com/en.php"));
    case 'pt':
        exit(header("Location: https://example.com/pt.php"));
endswitch;
if (false !== strpos($accept_languaje, 'es')) {
    exit(header("Location: https://example.com/"));
}
if (false !== strpos($accept_languaje, 'en')) {
    exit(header("Location: https://example.com/en.php"));
}
if (false !== strpos($accept_languaje, 'pt')) {
    exit(header("Location: https://example.com/pt.php"));
}
exit(header("Location: https://example.com/en.php"));
?>
```

Comment: I would say revisit your code again. This one seems to fine but if this file is being used in other file or any code that is redirecting to either this file or any other file that is redirecting to to main that would cause to become a infinite loop which is causing the issue you are having. 

Use echo and move on step by step you will definitely find the cause of redirecting

Comment: @NoumanAhmad i put this code at the top of my index.php :( i cant find the problem, im new in PHP

Comment: then this code would be causing the issue 

case 'es':
        exit(header("Location: https://example.com/"));

I believe you need to revisit your logic again. Here is something that comes up to my based upon your given code. You're trying to create a page that can show the text in multiple languages. if so,

- create separate language file
- put your different texts of multiple language there 
- use include/require to get those file into your index.php file and you will be able to get show the text in index.php file based upon required lang

Comment: @NoumanAhmad My idea is only to stop the redirection if it detects that I am already in (https://example.com) because the main language of my web is Spanish

Comment: But thanks for your idea, I will try to implement it! I will look for how to do it, but if you could help me with my original question I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove following and try

```
case 'es': 
exit(header("Location: example.com/")); 

if (false !== strpos($accept_languaje, 'es')) { exit(header("Location: example.com/")); }
```

Comment: I tried it and the too many redirects disappeared, but now I get an HTTP ERROR 500 :(

Comment: Try following functions to debug your code
echo or print_r